# CSS to Desaturate Background Image Only WIth Other Images in Div Stay Saturated

Tags: css

I am trying to desaturate the background image of a div while leaving the images within that same div saturated. I've found one example close to what I'm trying to do (except w/ blur) but have tried multiple variations of it w/ no success.

In the code below, the .desaturate class correctly applies the filter attributes and turns bg image into b&w. The other image w/in this section tag are inheriting the desaturate as would be expected, but when I try to "re-saturate" through the img.saturate class it is not being applied. I've whittled down my code to as short/basic as it can get to explain what I am trying to do. Any ideas or solution how this can be done is appreciated.

```
<html>
  <style>
    .desaturate {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-position: center center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
       /*grayscale for background image*/
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
      -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
      -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
      filter: gray; 
      filter: grayscale(100%);
      filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='0'><filter id='greyscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0' /></filter></svg>#greyscale");
    }

  img.saturate {
    filter: none !important;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%) !important;
    -moz-filter:    grayscale(0%) !important;
    -ms-filter:     grayscale(0%) !important;
    -o-filter:      grayscale(0%) !important;
  }
  </style>
  <body>
    <section class="desaturate" style="background-image: url('bg-img-1.jpg');">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img src="img-2.jpg" class="img-responsive saturate" alt="" />      
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Could you throw this into a JSFiddle or CodePen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saturation works in the same way as opacity does, you can't apply the effect to a parent and then undo it in a child. Your best option would probably be to make the grayscaled image a child of your section but not a parent of the image:

```
<section>
  <figure class="desaturate" style="background-image: url('bg-img-1.jpg');"></figure>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="img-2.jpg" class="img-responsive saturate" alt="" />      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Your other option would be to inherit the background in a `::before` or `::after` pseudo element and apply the filter there:

```
.desaturate {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.desaturate:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: inherit;
   /*grayscale for background image*/
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray; 
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='0'><filter id='greyscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0' /></filter></svg>#greyscale");
}
```

You can see a demo here: http://codepen.io/Godwin/pen/ogLPvR.

**Edit**:
Just for sake of interest, there is another way of doing this but it doesn't have high browser support yet:

```
.desaturate {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    /*grayscale for background image*/
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-blend-mode: luminosity, normal;
}
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode

Example: http://codepen.io/Godwin/pen/raLZVr

Support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode

Comment: same trick as advise for me if that suits your real document on line : my version http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxBJYm

Comment: Thank you... tried the :before based on the other example I posted in my question but couldnt get it right. This works exactly how I need it to. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

**Make your background image a child**

With your background image as a child, then you can apply a `filter` on the element.

```
filter: grayscale(60%);
-webkit-filter: grayscale(60%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(60%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(60%);
-o-filter: grayscale(60%);
```

**Alternatively, maintain your HTML structure, but only target the background-image...**

Concerning background image's, filters aren't available, however you can get the same saturation effect using this trick with `background-blend-mode`.

Usually `background-blend-mode` is on-or-off (ie you cannot define percentage), however with the below trick you can actually get variable saturation:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.6),rgba(0,0,0,0.6)), url(image.jpg);
background-blend-mode: saturation;
```

This will give you a 60% desaturation only on the background image, using `background-blend-mode`. The key is using linear-gradient, with opacity set on the colors. I can't seem to replicate the same effect *not* using a gradient (ie a solid color with opacity).

**Browser support:**

Both `filter` and `background-blend-mode` have weaker support in IE/Edge, so perhaps use separate CSS rules for those browsers (as described in tons of other posts).

Answer (score 0):

Here's your fix:

## [Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t56tmy7p/)

So, basically, your CSS is messed up pretty bad.  The dangling `!important` modifiers after your semi-colons and the haphazardly included semi-colons after that aren't helping.

**CSS Changes**

```
.desaturate {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
   
}

.desaturate img {
  /*grayscale for background image*/
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: gray; 
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' height='0'><filter id='greyscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0' /></filter></svg>#greyscale");
}



.desaturate img.saturate {
  filter: none !important;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
  -moz-filter:    grayscale(0%);
  -ms-filter:     grayscale(0%);
  -o-filter:      grayscale(0%);
}
```

You can't apply the filter to the whole `div` and then override it on a child element (in this case your `img`.  So we apply the filter to the `img` first, and then override it with your `saturate` class.

Voila.

Comment: sorry, yes I didn't have that in my original code (the extra semi-colons). My mistake in whittling it down and not double checking. I have corrected.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a backdrop-filter on your child element, as long as your child element is at the same size as the parent, this will grayscale any apparent elements behind it, without affecting its content.

**[Run example code snippet here](https://jsfiddle.net/qh3gan0z/15/)**

An untested example with your code might look like this:

```html
<style>
  .backdrop-grayscale {
    /* the idea is to get this div to expand */
    /* to the full size of the parent element */
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;

    /* this is the magic line */
    /* you can also use any other filter type (blur, invert, sepia, etc...) */
    backdrop-filter: grayscale(50%);
  }
</style>
<section style="background-image: url('bg-img-1.jpg');">
  <div class="row backdrop-grayscale">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <img src="img-2.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="" />      
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```